# Retrofit OnResponse method not working

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

this is my apicall

```
  public void loadData(String lat,String lon){
            pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pd.setMessage("Loading");
            pd.show();

            mApi = new RetrofitHelper<AuthApi>().getApi(AuthApi.class);

            currentCall = mApi.currentData(lat,lon,units,key);

            currentCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResultObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResultObject> call,
                                       Response<ResultObject> response) {

                    Log.d("enter","enter");
                    Log.d("temp",new Integer(response.body().getMain().getTemp()).toString());
                    temp_current.setText(new Integer(response.body().getMain().getTemp()).toString());

                    pd.hide();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResultObject> call, Throwable t) {
                    pd.hide();

                }
            });

        }
```

This logs with the keys "enter" and "temp" doesnot show  up on tbe logcat that means it is not entering the OnResponse method

this is my api request inteface

```
@GET("weather")
        Call<ResultObject> currentData(
                @Query("lat") String lat,
                @Query("lon") String lon,
                @Query("units") String units,
                @Query("APPID") String APPID
        );
```

this is my result class(json matching),just made required fields for the "main" field in json response.
i dont know if this ResultObject class is parsing the response or not

```
public class ResultObject{
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("message")
    public String message;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("result")
    public int result;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("main")
    public Main main;

    public class Main {

        @Expose
        @SerializedName("temp")
        public int temp;

        @Expose
        @SerializedName("pressure")
        public int pressure;

        @Expose
        @SerializedName("humidity")
        public int humidity;

        @Expose
        @SerializedName("temp_min")
        public int temp_min;

        @Expose
        @SerializedName("temp_max")
        public int temp_max;

        public int getTemp() {
            return temp;
        }

        public void setTemp(int temp) {
            this.temp = temp;
        }

        public int getPressure() {
            return pressure;
        }

        public void setPressure(int pressure) {
            this.pressure = pressure;
        }

        public int getHumidity() {
            return humidity;
        }

        public void setHumidity(int humidity) {
            this.humidity = humidity;
        }

        public int getTemp_min() {
            return temp_min;
        }

        public void setTemp_min(int result) {
            this.temp_min = temp_min;
        }

        public int getTemp_max() {
            return temp_max;
        }

        public void setTemp_max(int result) {
            this.temp_max = temp_max;
        }

    }

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("errors")
    public List<String> errors;

    public List<String> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    public void setErrors(List<String> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }


    public Main getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public void setmain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(int result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

I logged the response,which is this

```
    {"coord":{"lon":0,"lat":0},
"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],
"base":"stations",
"main":{"temp":25.71,"pressure":1026.51,"humidity":100,"temp_min":25.71,"temp_max":25.71,"sea_level":1026.58,"grnd_level":1026.51},
"wind":{"speed":6.41,"deg":190.004},
"clouds":{"all":92},
"dt":1497210848,
"sys":{"message":0.0084,"sunrise":1497160571,"sunset":1497204213},"id":6295630,"name":"Earth","cod":200}
```

I get the response but the OnResponse method does not work

I am not able resolve it, please help

Comment: I don't understand, onResponse method is not called? or you cannot parse the response with the ResultObject class?

Comment: What's the response of the logging you've written in the onResponse method? Is the response cancelled? And also, you may be looking for `Integer.toString(...getTemp())` rather than boxing the int and then outputting it as a String

Comment: The logs with the keys "enter" and "temp" doesnot show in the logcat

Comment: @fechidal89 yes i guess the ResultObject class is not parsing the response

Comment: @AllanW The logs with the keys "enter" and "temp" doesnot show-up in the logcat(android monitor),so OnResponse method is not working

Comment: You can't call `response.body()` more than once. Nor should you

Comment: Your JSON doesn't match your class at all...

Comment: And you're ignoring the error message in onFailure, so start fixing your code there, then [edit] your question to include the logcat

Comment: One problem I can found in your code is your model class is not matching with JSON structure. First log OnFailour message and check whats wrong in your code.